# Tabularray and rgb xcolor option

Tags: color, tabularray

When I use the rgb otion of `xcolor` package and `tabularray` package I got a lot of errors.

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `rgb:Hsb'.
```

Is it possible to pass this option to xcolor and use tabularray?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
Tabularray
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See https://github.com/latex3/xcolor/issues/1

Before the issue of `xcolor` package is fixed, you can use the following workaround:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}

\selectcolormodel{natural}
\usepackage{ninecolors}
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{colspec={lcr},rowspec={|Q[cyan7]|Q[azure7]|Q[blue7]|}}
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma  \\
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta    \\
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A more minimal example showing that `tabularray` is only marginally involved:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ninecolors}

\begin{document}

Tabularray

\end{document}
```

This fails with the same error message as your example, namely

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color model `rgb:Hsb'.
```

Where does `ninecolors` come from? At some point, `tabularray` does

```
\AtBeginDocument{\@ifpackageloaded{xcolor}{\RequirePackage{ninecolors}}{}}
```

so the problem is in compatibility of `ninecolors` with options passed to `xcolor`.

Solution? Remove the option `rgb` and try to contact the author of `ninecolors`.

Comment: hm, I fear it is a xcolor bug. The color definition is a valid syntax but fails with the package option.