# \makecell with typeface and line break

Tags: tables, line-breaking, tabularx, makecell, typefaces

I'm having a bit of trouble using typefaces like `\textbf` or `\spacedlowsmallcaps` in `\makecell`s with line breaks.
The following code works:

```latex
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{HEADER 1} & \spacedlowsmallcaps{Header 2} & \spacedlowsmallcaps{Header 3} \\
        \midrule
        cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

If however, let's say the second header is very long and needs a line break and I want to use `\makecell` to get nice formatting, I get an error:

```latex
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{HEADER 1} & \makecell[c]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Very Long Header 2\\that needs a line break}} & \spacedlowsmallcaps{Header 3} \\
        \midrule
        cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Here, LaTeX throws multiple instances of the following errors at me:

```
Missing } inserted.
  <inserted text>
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
  <recently read> \egroup
```

Why is this and how do I fix it?
I know I can just split the long text like

```latex
\spacedlowsmallcaps{Very Long Header 2}\\\spacedlowsmallcaps{that needs a line break}
```

But that makes the code much more cluttered and it doesn't work if I want to use it inside a `newcommand` where I just pass text that may or may not contain a line break.

**EDIT 1:** To be more clear: the same applies when I replace `\spacedlowsmallcaps` with something like `\textbf` or `\textit`.

**EDIT 2:** As requested, here is a full document illustrating the problem:

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\newcommand{\tableheader}[2]{\makecell[#1]{\textbf{#2}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        % \textbf{HEADER 1} & \makecell[c]{\textbf{Very Long Header 2\\that needs a line break}} & \textbf{Header 3} \\
        % the above line does not work
        % \textbf{HEADER 1} & \makecell[c]{\textbf{Very Long Header 2}\\\textbf{that needs a line break}} & \textbf{Header 3} \\
        % this line is syntactically correct,
        % but it becomes a problem when using it with a predefined command:
        \tableheader{l}{HEADER 1} & \tableheader{c}{Very Long Header 2\\that needs a line break} & \tableheader{c}{Header 3} \\
        \midrule
        cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: PLease provide complete small document, which we can test as it is. Where is defined `\spacedlowsmallcaps`?

Comment: It's from the classicthesis.sty which can be found at http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis/classicthesis.sty. The same applies for `\textbf` or `\textit` though.

Comment: Please again, provide complete small document. Why should we google and make it if you already have it. Anyway, Test my answer if works. And see too, how this is "simple", if is provided only code fragment ... (which are surely correct)

Comment: I provided a small example

Comment: And what is the problem in this example? The same approach is considered in my answer ...

Comment: As I said, if I want to make a separate command with just one argument to shorten things and make them more readable, then this approach doesn't work. I'll edit my question shortly with a quick example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of reinventing the wheel, use the `\thead` macro which the `makecell` package provides for such cases:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
         \thead{HEADER 1} & \thead[c]{Very Long Header 2\\that needs a line break} & \thead{Header 3} \\
        \midrule
        cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One quick question though: How would I change the font to the `\spacedlowsmallcaps`? I know I have to use `\theadfont`, but just setting it to this doesn't work. It is declared as: `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{\textls[80]{\ct@caps\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}` or `\DeclareRobustCommand{\spacedlowsmallcaps}[1]{{\addfontfeatures{LetterSpace=14.0}\ct@caps\MakeTextLowercase{#1}}}`

Comment: @Lithimlin If your header is lowercase, you could use `\renewcommand\theadfont{\slshape\scshape}`

Comment: unfortunately, they aren't by default. I'd ave to be careful to always type them in lowercase

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**
Using `makcell` each line which is formated with some command, as are `\textbf{...}` or `\spacedlowsmallcaps{...}` had to be closed before is line terminated. So,

```
\makecell[c]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Very Long Header 2 \\
                                 that needs a line break}}
```

is wrong and

```
\makecell[c]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Very Long Header 2}\\
             \spacedlowsmallcaps{that needs a line break}}
```

is correct.

According to above rule, your code fragment should be written as:

```
\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
        \textbf{HEADER 1} & \spacedlowsmallcaps{Header 2} & \spacedlowsmallcaps{Header 3} \\
        \midrule
        cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcc}
        \toprule
\textbf{HEADER 1} & \makecell[c]{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Very Long Header 2}\\ 
                                 \spacedlowsmallcaps{that needs a line break}}
                    & \spacedlowsmallcaps{Header 3} \\
        \midrule
        cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3 \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={lcc}, row{1}={m}}
        \toprule
\textbf{HEADER 1} & {\spacedlowsmallcaps{Very Long Header 2}\\
                     \spacedlowsmallcaps{that needs a line break}}
                    & \spacedlowsmallcaps{Header 3} \\
        \midrule
        cell 1 & cell 2 & cell 3 \\
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
```

I will be able to complete provided code fragment when you will provide complete small document with your tables.

For the last table you need to load  in preamble.

```
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
```

**Addendum:**

- At cases, when command for formatting text can be replaced by switch, for example `\textbf{...}` by `\bfseries`, you can write

```
\textbf{HEADER 1} & \bfseries\makecell[c]{Very Long Header 2\\
                                          that needs a line break}
                    & \textbf{Header 3} \\
```

which is equivalent to solution proposed in @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz answer.

- in similar cases the use of `tabularry` package can be very handy. For example, the example, which you add to question, can be written as:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec={lcc},
             row{1} = {font=\bfseries, c, m}
             }
    \toprule
HEADER 1    &  {Very Long Header 2\\ that needs a line break}
                        & header 3  \\
    
    \midrule
cell 1      & cell 2    & cell 3    \\
cell 1      & cell 2    & cell 3    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your proposed final solution does not compile for me. I get several errors in `ninecolors.sty` and cannot figure out where they're coming from. I tried moving around the import a bit but without any success.

Comment: @Lithimlin, you have not loaded `tabularray` package. Load it.

Comment: You mean like in lines 2 and 3? I have done that. That's what I meant when I said I tried moving around the imports.

Comment: @Lithimlin, sorry, I do not understood, what you trying to tell me.

Comment: You said I had not loaded `tabularray`, but I had added the package (like you did in lines 2 and 3 of your example) but I still got the error

Comment: @Lithimlin, oh, you not understood me. Do you have load package `tabularray` in your LaTeX installation?  If yes, than last example as it is  should work, if not, load it on the way as is supported by your LaTeX installation.

Comment: Ah, the problem was actually a different one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614621/tabularray-and-rgb-xcolor-option

Comment: @Lithimlin, sory, than you change my suggested code and add some color into table . In such a case you should load in preamble  `xtabular` package too.

Comment: The color was actually not used for a table. It was another leftover from something else I'd missed to comment out. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Lithimlin, if now is all clarify, then is time to accept one from received answers (which you most liked). As I see, so far you not accept any answer on your question(s). For accešpting just click on check mark at top left side of selected answer.